# Why is it called final/initial topology?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

Why is the final topology called "final"? And why is the initial topology called "initial"?

Comment: I don't know who named these, but perhaps because the final topology is a topology we give to a set which is the _target_ of a collection of maps, and the initial topology is a topology we give to a set which is the _domain_ of a collection of maps.

Comment: Lewis: Ah, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "initial" because we define a new topology on a set $X$ when we have maps $f_i:X \to (Y_i, \mathcal{T}_i), i \in I$ that must become continuous. So the initial topology defined at the "start" of the arrows.

Same with "final" and the fact that we define a topology on the common codomain of a family $f_i: (X_i, \mathcal{T}_i) \to X, i \in I$, so at the "end" of the arrows. That's how it was taught to me anyway.

There is a nice symmetry there also in that final topologies are maximal and initial topologies are minimal (we always have at least one topology that trivially works, discrete for the initial situation, indicrete for the final one). The set of maps is called a "sink" (final) or a "source" (initial) as well, also exploiting the direction analogy (as if the arrow is streaming water). I'm no historian of topology but I think the terminology started with German "categorical topologists" like Preuss and Herrlich.